# Need help putting two potentiometers in series?

Tags: resistance, potentiometer

I'm currently doing a project to control the speed of a dc motor, I'm on a budget and trying to find parts that I have. I have found two 50k potentiometers that I would like to put in series to add up the resistance to get 100k, the potentiometers job is to control the speed of the motor. I have done it before, but that was when I just bought the right pot. Now I would like to run them in series and do it that way.

**If I have two 50k potentiometers, can I use them to get a variable resistance between 0 and 100k, and if so how do I connect them?**

Comment: Each wiper only covers a 50kohm range...

Comment: *"And do not tell me it can't be done because I have done it before"* - So, why don't you just do it again?

Comment: There are very few applications where you can't safely replace a 100k pot with a 50k pot. What makes you think this is one of them? Schematic and links to motor controller (board or IC) would help answer the question.

Comment: Let me tell you: you can't do it. There I said it. You can do it with a potmeter and a motor control circuit. But only a potmeter of 50k, no. A wire-wound potmeter of 100 ohms: maybe, it depends on the motor.

Comment: obliviously you didn't read the question, yes i have done it before but that was using one 100k pot. In this case i have no money at the moment and would like to use what i have on hand. So I have two 50k pot and would like to put them in series to get 100k.

Comment: @JoeyRus So, you *haven't* done it before then?

Comment: I don't understand the actual question here, don't you know how to put them in series?

Comment: well i know using 100k pot will work, i i'm doing this for a project at school and someone else has it done and working. building the schematic is very easy. Just need someone that knows what there doing to help. So again please do not say it cant be done with 100% it can be.

Comment: If i knew how to put them in series, I would not be on this website. The question is very clear.

Comment: I have done this project before, I never put potentiometers in series. I put resistors in series 100's times.

Comment: There is no single question in the body of your question, if it would be very clear, I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @JoeyRus Are you asking *"If I have two 50k potentiometers, can I use them to get a variable resistance between 0 and 100k, and if so how do I connect them"*?

Comment: Yes roger rowland that is what i i'm asking.

Comment: I should of been more clear, I apologize about that.

Comment: @JoeyRus Ok, we got there in the end, and I see you now have an answer.

Comment: Questions like this need to be reworded. There is no shame in not having four dollars to buy a ganged component. OP appears to have been asking for a mechanical solution involving gears or drivewheels/belts ala early 20th century bakelite era. I am pretty sure the OP understands the  resistors in series concept.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the way you must use it there are different ways to use them:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fckhSu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpCSzJ.png)</sup>

Note that the operation is of course different, as you have two wipers to control the value and you will have multiple wiper settings resulting in the same total resistance which makes labelling the potentiometers impossible.

And you will have some performance degradation because of 2 wipers (increase in wiper resistance).

Comment: Thank you arenal, I have complete your answer and my potentimeters produce 100k. well 95.5k but it will do, again thank you very much.